# Почему ошибка Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'var' was corrupted.

Tags: c++, указатели, память, динамические-массивы, стек

По завершению работы функции выдает ошибку

иногда это

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'corrW_' was
>   corrupted.

а иногда вот это

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'w_' was
>   corrupted.

Грешил, что памяти мало выделяется, так нет всё в порядке.

```
    double *corrW_ = new double[l_];
    ::ReadFile(file_, &corrW_, (sizeof(corrW_[0])*l_), &fl, NULL);
    ::SetFilePointer(file_, mfl, 0, FILE_CURRENT);
    int qw_ = 0;
    qw_ += s_in_*nl_[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < l_ - 1; i++)
        qw_ += nl_[i] * nl_[i+1];

    double ***w_ = new double**[l_];    
    for (int i = 0; i < l_; i++) {  
        w_[i] = new double*[nl_[i]];    
        for (int j = 0; j < nl_[i]; j++) {  
            w_[i][j] = new double[(i == 0) ? s_in_ :
                (nl_[j])];  
        }   
    }

    ::ReadFile(file_, &w_, sizeof(w_[0][0][0])*qw_, &fl, NULL);
```

Что здесь может быть не так?

Answer (score 0):

Передача указателя на переменную `&corrW_` приводит к записи прочитанных данных в эту переменную, а не в буфер, на которые она указывает.

Во втором случае проблема еще серьезнее, так как прочитать данные во множество буферов за один проход не получится.

Что касается `double ***` - [Three Star Programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: то есть в corrW_ придется записывать поэлементно передавая &corrW_[0] ... и т.д. и соответственно в w_ так же перебирая элементы. Я правильно понял?

Comment: @Кирилл Нет, надо передавать указатель на буфер с double

Comment: @Кирилл: Никакого "поэлементно" тут не надо. Почему вы написали `&` перед `corrW_` при чтении? Чего вы хотели добиться этим `&`?